# It all return default value, which is "No", when I want to get dropdown value

Tags: magento-enterprise

I add a new attribute at backend called **`eol`** to identify the product is ***end of life or not***. Then, there are several `.phtml` files should be modified. Now, I modified a file here:

```
app\design\frontend\enterprise\arctic_enterprise\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

and it works well. It is used to display end of life sign in the product description page.

Then I want to modify a file here:

```
app\design\frontend\enterprise\arctic_enterprise\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
```

But it doesn't work. It is used to display end of life sign in the product sub-category.

Here is the code which is really easy:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('eol')
                 ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
print_r($attribute);

if ($attribute == 'Yes') {
    $_isEOL = true;
} else {
    $_isEOL = false;
}
```

The idea is to fetch the value of attribute, which is `eol`, when the page is loading. I used print_r($attribute); to display the value of $attribute, they are all return default value, which is `no`.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_product->getEol()` It should return `0` or `1`.

If you get 0 and you shouldn't then check if you set the value at the store view level.